# Wrong statics destruction order after opening/closing a shared library more than once

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a weird problem with a C++ shared library on Linux.

The process loads and unloads my library twice (it is by design and cannot be changed).

1. During the first dlopen(), all static members in my library are initialized in a corrected order.
2. Then, when the first dlclose() is called, the destruction goes also as expected, in the order opposite to the construction.
3. During the second dlopen(), everything is okay - the order of construction is correct, same as the first time.
4. But on the second dlclose() the order of destruction suddenly gets broken - the destructors are called in the same order as they were initialized, and it often causes a SEGFAULT if any static object attempts to access an already destroyed object.
5. Subsequent attempts to dlopen()/dlclose() repeat the 3rd and 4th steps exactly.

I've attempted to reproduce the problem with a minimal example, but did not succeed - with a small fake shared library everything works as expected. There is something in my large library that causes the havoc on the second dlclose(), and it is very large.

I did not find dependency on gcc (tried 3.2/3.4/4.1.2) nor Linux distro (RHEL 4/5, SuSE 10). Search for similar cases in Web resulted in 0 results - nothing similar.

During the experiments, I've tried to embed a few calls to atexit() in static object constructors, to see if the order of atexit() handlers gets affected, and found that it does. Steps 1/2/3 works well (dlopen/dlclose/dlopen), then on the second dlclose the order of the atexit-registered handlers is incorrect.

I don't really expect to get an answer, but I would most appreciate any suggestions of how to pursue the problem.

Thank you in advance,

Andrew Schetinin

P.S. Update - I debugged the code in atexit() in GLIBC and found that there is a bug I'm hitting - quite a simple bug, actually. It is fixed in GLIBC 2.4, and I was unlucky to work with GLIBC 2.3.4

Comment: I debugged the code in atexit() in GLIBC and found that there is a bug I'm hitting - quite a simple bug, actually. It is fixed in GLIBC 2.4, and I was unlucky to work with GLIBC 2.3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in GLIBC 2.3.x that was fixed in GLIBC 2.4.

The bug is triggered under very specific conditions - when a process opens and closes a C++ library with a lot of static variables in different object files more than once.

atexit() entries are organized in a single-linked list of arrays of 32 handler pointers, and the old code in atexit() inserted new handlers into a wrong page in single-linked list, thus breaking atexit() contract of calling to finalization handlers in the reverse order of their registration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you may rely on static ctor/dtor order by any stretch of the imagination.  You just aren't offered any assurances.

I would expect to see setup and teardown functions that you only call once each.  Making sure that you do this once is yours to enforce.

Comment: While I cannot rely on the order of initialization in my sources, after the library is compiled and linked, the linker "freezes" the order. And BTW, in most modern linkers there are certain conventions of how the initialization is ordered (direct order in gcc, opposite order in Sun C++, and fully controlled order in IBM C++). My problem is not that. My problem is that the order is broken after reload of a shared library, which is something I never would expect to happen.

Comment: You say they have these conventions, freezes, etc, but your evidence does not support it.  Static memory can't rely on initialization order.  Maybe it will work for months and then for some obscure heuristic the tool chain will change is strategies and will not tell you why.

Comment: Again, in 99% cases it works correctly - otherwise C++ software could hardly be written at all - it relies on a lot of assumptions due to the lack of standardized way of doing all those things like shared libraries. In my case I believe it's a bug I hit, and I have it 100% reproducible for a single specific library. I'm lacking ideas of what to do about it :-)

Comment: C++ standard explicitly states that (simplified) the order or destruction of static objects is reverse from their construction order.